# How to create a Bubble chart timeline in R on one horizontal line

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeline, bubble-chart

I would like to create a bubble chart in R where each bubble represents a mass shooting: casualties `Killed` and casualties `Injured`something like the following:

[image: FTData timeline]

Basically, I want a `ggplot2` bubble chart with `geom_point` on **one** horizontal line. Without a y-axis, where the size of the points represent the values (`Killed` and `Injured`).

For reproducibility, you can find my dataset of mass shootings in the US (2017) in [a shared google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nq5AK3Y1uXQJ8wTm14w9MkZOwAxHHTyPyEvUxCeGVc/edit?usp=sharing). (*Do note that the terrible mass shooting in Las Vegas is left out for gradual points size purposes, I will add the one later on*).

I created the following plot, but as described I would like to have all the dots (killed and Injured) on one horizontal line.

```
  data_per_date %>%
  filter(Incident.Date != "2017-10-01") %>% # Las Vegas shooting is left out for size purposes.
  ggplot(aes(x = Incident.Date, y = Killed)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Injured),
             shape = 21,
             colour = "#FF6F00") + # Should be the orange transparant circles 
  geom_point(aes(size = Killed),
             alpha = 0.7,
             colour = "#B71C1C") # The red bubbles
```

[image]

- **P.s.** It's quite a lot to ask, I know, but I can't find any timelines like these created with R. You smart people maybe have some Ideas of how to tackle this problem.
- **P.S. 2** I could align the points in a vector graphic tool like Skech or Illustrator but rather want to know how to do this in R.

Comment: Try `aes(x = Incident.Date, y=0)` instead of what you have got in your third line.  You will need to play around with the axis options to get it looking as you want.

Comment: Man... very simple but effective thanks!